# MvvmCross Droid ContentPresenter + Template equivalent

Tags: mvvmcross

How could I achieve something similar as WPF's ContentPresenter + UI Template in MvvmCross/Droid?

A region on the screen will display a ViewModel. Depending on the ViewModel, a Layout View (DataTemplate) will be used to present the ViewModel.

note: This is not about lists

Thanks!

Comment: Try http://twitter.com/luisruizpavon for a controls plugin (on mobile and that's the best link I've got!)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Stuart.

https://github.com/ChristianRuiz/MvvmCross-ControlsNavigation

http://www.nuget.org/packages/MupApps.MvvmCross.Plugins.ControlsNavigation